# R - Manually Change the Column Number Positions

Tags: r

This is a bit of an odd request, but I have a specific need that I am try to solve.

Lets pretend I have a dataframe with 50 columns. The column number (or index) of each column will be 1:50 respectively. Is there a way that I can assign new column numbers to each of the 50? Lets say that I want the first column to have a column number that is 187. Is this possible?

I have a predictive model that when built memorizes the column positions of each variable that was used to build the model, instead of the variable names. In my original dataset, I had 1,559 variables to build the model, but only 50 were selected as part of the final model. The model remembers each variable position as a function of the 1,559 however, so when I go to score new data it is looking for 1559 variables instead of just the 50 I have brought into my scoring universe.

I have saved the original position numbers of each variable, so I was hoping I could just assign column numbers to a dataset with only 50 variables. I have a workaround where I build a big empty dataframe with 1559 columns, and then put the data into the correct column # and then score the data, but in this case I have 3 million records to score, and I dont have enough RAM to build a 3M row, 1559 column dataframe.

Comment: In theory there's nothing stopping you from doing, say, `names(mtcars)[1] <- "187"` and extracting that column via `mtcars[,"187"]`, but this isn't a number, it's a character string.

Comment: @WeihuangWong Yes, I did understand that would change the name of the column, but not update the actual column index number. Maybe its not possible to tell R a column index # is something that it actually isnt.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the column position directly via `data[,c(ORDER YOU WANT THEM TO BE IN)]`

For instance:

`head(cars)`

vs.

`head(cars[,c(2,1)])`

Comment: You must not have read my question, thats not what I am trying to do. I dont want to take 50 variables and reorder them, I want to have a dataframe with 50 variables, but make R think that variable 1 is Column # 150, and variable 2 is Column # 276, etc. The end result being, can I manually assign column # positions, even if those positions dont exist.

Comment: You must not have considered my answer, because it is exactly what you should be trying to do.

You should reconsider trying to "make R think that variable 1 is column 150" and just assign variable 1 as column 150. This will make R think that variable 1 is column 150 because variable 1 is column 150.

Comment: sorry Glenn, but we still aren't on the same page. I am not trying to reorder my variables,this is a basic task. You missed the part I only have a dataset with 50 variables , so variable 150 doesn't exist at all. But I want R to think the column index of the first variable is 150.